# How to use Angular JS on Web api result

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I am just trying to connect MongoDB using Web api.

I followed steps present in
http://www.sunyingroup.com/web2012/mongapi.htm

I confused with step **3, Build Angular JS MVC Pattern** .

My question is how/where to add Angularjs script present in the above mentioned website.

Comment: do you have an html-template for the angular-script

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your link example, it uses MVC page but that page is not provided (they provided just the javascript code), but basically you can go with a pure html file where you define your grid to show the data, and add your button. you need to add ng-app directive to body tag of the html file with app named after their module name "CRUD", and include that code into a javascript tag, in the same file for example or separate file.

the following link gives you a starting point of how to use angularjs with API

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/737030/A-basic-SPA-application-using-AngularJS-WebAPI-and

hope that helps.